# Whenever I create an activity there is a content_activity created at the same time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For example, I build a new blank activity named main_activity and there will be a main_content_activity created at the same time automatically.

What is this and how to use it?

I got this problem after I download some templates from Github...
Can anyone solve this?

Because the reputation, I can't upload images....

Comment: its ur xml layout file. whats the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It because you updated Android Studio to latest version 1.4 which updates Activity templates to use Design Support Library - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/09/android-studio-14.html

And now when you want to create blank activty, it generates two xml layout files. For example for activity named MainActivity, there will be generated  `activity_main.xml` and `content_main.xml`. First contains base stuff from Design Support Library (`CoordinatorLayout`, `Toolbar`, `AppBarLayout`), and second contains layout you should edit with your stuff (this content_main layout is in fact included to activity_main layout).

If you want to create the most clean Activity, then you should use Empty Activity template, not blank.